# How to call two function together in etherjs

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, dapps, ethers.js

Hello i am trying to mint nft with erc20  but need approval of token first so i wrote code but calling only approval not mint after that can someomne help out i wrote in etherjs

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";
import { Box, Button, Flex, Input, Text, tokenToCSSVar } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ABI from "./Token.json"
const TokenAdress = "0x4f69617971E52dC61727f8053477cd8862799F1c"
const NFTAddress = "0x4A5133f045832304ccaCAF8c912Aa073DF6C5F28"
const MaintMint = ({ accounts, setAccounts }) => {
  const [mintAmount, setMintAmount] = useState(1);
  const isConnected = Boolean(accounts[0]);

  async function handleMint() {
    const abiResponse = await fetch("/NFT.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }

     

    });
    const abi = await abiResponse.json();
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        NFTAddress,
        abi,
        signer
      );
      const ContractWithSigner = contract.connect(signer);
      try {
        let Token = new ethers.Contract(TokenAdress, ABI, signer);
       
        let amount = "1000000000"
        const tx = await Token.approve(NFTAddress, amount)
       
       
        await tx.wait()
        const response = await ContractWithSigner.safeMint()
        console.log("response: ", response);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Potentially helpful: [Multicall](https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-multicall).

Answer (score 1):

i think you forget something after calling mint function

```
const response = await ContractWithSigner.safeMint()
response.wait(); //  add this 
console.log("response: ", response);
```

try adding it.

Comment: hello mate thanks a lot it works i got stuck at that you helped me out :b

Comment: no problem mate